# Xcode changes remoteGlobalIDString - how to avoid?

Tags: xcode, version-control

My "project.pbxproj" is under version control. Xcode keeps changing the `remoteGlobalIDString` of libraries linked via a subproject.

Does anyone else have this problem? If yes, what can I do about it?

```
5A1F61F5162C0F6B001ABF64 /* PBXContainerItemProxy */ = {
        isa = PBXContainerItemProxy;
        containerPortal = 5A0A1B5816147A4A00C65C6D /* MyReferencedSubProject.xcodeproj */;
        proxyType = 1;
        remoteGlobalIDString = 235B356E47F64C9DB6D76F45; << THIS CHANGES ALL THE TIME
        remoteInfo = MyLibInMySubProject;
    };
```

Comment: I just realized it seems to be related to the fact that `MyLibInMySubProject` is a target dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way fix it for me was to rewrite the project UUIDs generated by cmake:

```
YOUR_TARGET_UUID=$(grep -E -m 1 '[A-F0-9]{24} \/\* YOUR_TARGET \*\/ = {' \
                    "Project.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj" | \
                 grep -o -E '[A-F0-9]{24}')
sed -i '' "s/${YOUR_TARGET_UUID}/00000000DEADBEEF00000000/g" \
          "Project.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj"
```